# Form POST method is not sending any data

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a form set into my html page:

```
<form action='savephp.php' name="writingData" id="writingData" method="post">
<textarea id="content">Hello, World!</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="submitButton">
</form>
```

and the receiving php is:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['writingData'];
if ($data === NULL) {
echo 'is null';
}
else {
file_put_contents("writingdata.txt", $data);
echo $data;
}
?>
```

However, I get the "is null" error every time I attempt to post. Im hitting a dead end, Ive tried changing up the `form name`, using the `textarea id`. I keep getting a null response. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: the form `name` is not sent. You have to assign `name` to `<textarea>`: `<textarea id="content" name="writingData">`. Also note that `id` is not sent.

Comment: ID is not sent in POST. You need name.

Answer (score 1):

textarea needs a name attribute

```
<textarea id="content" name="txtareaContent"></textarea>
```

then you can fetch it in savephp.php like this

```
$data = $_POST['txtareaContent'];
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='savephp.php' name="writingData" id="writingData" method="post">
<textarea id="content" name=="content">Hello, World!</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="submitButton">
</form>

<?php
$data = $_POST['content'];
if ($data === NULL) {
echo 'is null';
}
else {
file_put_contents("writingdata.txt", $data);
echo $data;
}
?>
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: Maybe try adding what you changed to make the code work.